# Syntax error: “(” unexpected (expecting “fi”)

Tags: shell, scripting, syntax-error, sh

```
filein="users.csv"

IFS=$'\n'

if [ ! -f "$filein" ]

then

  echo "Cannot find file $filein"

else

  #...

  groups=(`cut -d: -f 6 "$filein" | sed 's/ //'`)

  fullnames=(`cut -d: -f 1 "$filein"`)

  userid=(`cut -d: -f 2 "$filein"`)

  usernames=(`cut -d: -f 1 "$filein" | tr [A-Z] [a-z] | awk '{print substr($1,1,1) $2}'`)


  #...

  for group in ${groups[*]}

  do

    grep -q "^$group" /etc/group ; let x=$?

    if [ $x -eq 1 ]

    then

      groupadd "$group"

    fi

  done


 #...

  x=0

  created=0

  for user in ${usernames[*]}

  do

    useradd -n -c ${fullnames[$x]} -g "${groups[$x]}" $user 2> /dev/null

    if [ $? -eq 0 ]

    then

      let created=$created+1

    fi


 #...

    echo "${userid[$x]}" | passwd --stdin "$user" > /dev/null

    #...

    echo "Welcome! Your account has been created.  Your username is $user and temporary 
password is \"$password\" without the quotes." | mail -s "New Account for $user" -b root $user

    x=$x+1

    echo -n "..."

    sleep .25

  done

  sleep .25

  echo " " 

  echo "Complete. $created accounts have been created."

fi
```

Comment: To format code, paste exactly what you have, highlight it all, then click the `{}` icon.

Comment: SO is not a debugging service.  If you're having a specific problem, post the smallest amount of code that reproduces it ..

Comment: See also http://www.sscce.org/ -- if instructions there were followed, this question would be getting considerably less by way of unhappy feedback / downvotes.

Comment: @Richard, why put the extra vertical whitespace back in? I think r2 was much more readable than r3.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the problem is that you're trying to capture command output in arrays without actually using command substitution. You want something like this:

```
groups=( $( cut... ) )
```

Note the extra set of parentheses with `$` in front of the inner set.

Comment: Not good practice without some safeties -- for instance, if `cut` emitted `*`, it would be glob-expanded; if it emitted a value containing an IFS character it would be split on same, etc. `readarray -t groups < <(cut ...)` is safer.

Comment: True.  Wasn't approving the practice, just pointing out the apparent broken syntax.